# android: onclick event in listview using fragments

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

please tell me how will i go on the next page when i click on listview..it goes on to next activty

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
```

public class FragMent1 extends Fragment {

```
private String arry[] = { "Tofeeq", "Ahmad", "Fragment", "Example",
        "Tofeeq", "Ahmad", "Fragment", "Example" };

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ListView listView = new ListView(getActivity());
    ArrayAdapter<String> array = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    for (String str : arry)
        array.add(str);
    listView.setAdapter(array);
    return listView;
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), NextActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });

    return root;

}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you are in a fragment you have to use** `getActivity()` instead of `CurrentActivity.this`

```
import android.widget.AdapterView;



 public class FragMent1 extends Fragment {

        private String arry[] = { "Tofeeq", "Ahmad", "Fragment", "Example",
                "Tofeeq", "Ahmad", "Fragment", "Example" };

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View root = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, container, false);

  ListView lv = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listviewid);
            ArrayAdapter<String> array = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
            for (String str : arry)
                array.add(str);
            lv.setAdapter(array);


      lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {

                  Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), NextActivity.class);
                  startActivity(myIntent);
                    }
                });

    return root;
        }
    }
```

`listviewid` is your ListView id which you have set in your Layout.  `yourlayout` yourlayout.xml ?

Add your new activity in manifest file: inside `<application>` tag

```
<application>
     <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="NextActivity"/>
</application>
```

Add this ListView to your xml

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:background="@drawable/bg" 
android:id="@+id/yourlayout"> 


 <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listviewid"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: not yet resolved i am getting errors

Comment: please write the whole code thanks in advance

Comment: Updated My answer `NextActivity.class` should be your next activity

Comment: what error you actually facing ?

Comment: onitemclickListner() and rootview is red in my code

Comment: cannot resolve symbol 'onitemclicklistener'
cannot resolve symbol ';rootView'

Comment: Updated ans please check now . please import `import android.widget.AdapterView;`

Comment: i have imported this i am still getting this error

Comment: Could you please  update ur question and post full code?

Comment: Updated my answer check this

Comment: please check i have updated

Comment: i want to go onto new activity when i click on the list item example click on Tofeeq-->tofeeq activity appears

Comment: Did you try my code I have updated ans

Comment: i have tried but i am getting errors

Comment: `listviewid` is your ListView id which you have set in your Layout.  `yourlayout` yourlayout.xml ?  did you change this ? and what error you had ?

Comment: @SaadKhan you are very new I think

Comment: yes  i am very new no there is no id of the listview in the layout

Comment: its is the main layout
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout">
</RelativeLayout>

Comment: please make this right for me

Comment: there is no listview in the xml

Comment: check the layout xml i have updated . please change your code with mine

Comment: why would i add the listview in the xml if the list is appearing without adding and it is the actionbar xml

Comment: Sorry saad please learn the basic first then ask question here

Comment: thanks budd you were right

Answer (score 1):

Simply doing this:

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

               /* do what you want here, like changing fragment */
            }
        });
```

Now you can use it to load your next page.

What I suggest if you are in my case and if you use the same template of list is to use the bundle to know how to fill your listview, and the listener to change.

As an example, this is how I do to access the next page of a listview containing some countries, if I want to access a list of state for the selected country:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("type", "state");
                bundle.putString("value", ((TextView) arg1).getText().toString());
                FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
                AlphabeticalListViewFragment liste = new AlphabeticalListViewFragment();
                liste.setArguments(bundle);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, liste, "listfragment");
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(liste.getClass().getName());
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Then just read your bundle to know how to fill your list:

```
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
String typeListe= bundle.getString("type", "country");
if(typeListe.equals("country"))
        {...
```

Comment: listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

               /* please tell me what will i add here as i am new to android development and it is my learning process please reply*/
            }
        });

Comment: Put there what i put in my second block of code. Its an example to chance fragment. Adapt it for your needs.

Comment: listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

               /* please tell me what will i add here as i am new to the android*/
            }
        });

Answer (score 0):

```
  public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

        private String arry[] = { "Tofeeq", "Ahmad", "Fragment", "Example",
                "Tofeeq", "Ahmad", "Fragment", "Example" };

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, container, false);

  ListView lv = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listviewid);
            ArrayAdapter<String> array = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
            for (String str : arry)
                array.add(str);
            lv.setAdapter(array);


      lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {

                  Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
                  CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                    }
                });

    return view;
        }

    }
```

Add your new activity in manifest file:

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="NextActivity"/>
```

Comment: listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) { /* please tell me what will i add here as i am new to android development and it is my learning process please reply*/ } });

Comment: listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

               /* please tell me what will i add here as i am new to the android*/
            }
        });

Comment: What do you want to do when list item is clicked??

Comment: i want it to go on the next fragment or class

Comment: check the updated answer.Replace CurrentActivity and NextActivity with your activity names

Comment: not yet resolved i am getting errors

Comment: please write the whole code thanks in advance

Comment: first of all, learn the basic structure of a class.

Comment: i am stil getting the error

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: cannot resolve symbol 'onitemclicklistener' cannot resolve symbol ';rootView'

Comment: import onItemClickListener

Comment: did you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need **ListView.OnItemClickListener**

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html

Implement the listener and determine which is clicked by position param from listener method.